# Handling HTML SELECT Options with event delegation to javascript on iPhone Safari

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, events, safari

We are developing a web application with GUI customized to use on iPhone. A page on the app has 3 subsequent SELECT dropdowns, where selection of an option from 1st dropdown derives the options for 2nd dropdown, and so forth. The subsequent dropdown options are populated by javascript based on onchange event on previous dropdown. 
The problem is that, on iPhone the options for a SELECT appears with 'prev' and 'next' links to move to previous and next control. When the 'next' link is clicked, then the control moves to next SELECT and displays the options. The javascript is triggered by onchange event for previous SELECT and populates the options for next SELECT. But on dropdown for 2nd SELECT displays the previous options before it is repopulated by the javascript. 
Is there a workaround or event that can sequence execution of javascript and then selection of next control? Is there any event that can be triggered when a SELECT option is selected and before control leaves the SELECT element? Is there a handle for Next and Previous links for SELECT dropdown option display?

Comment: I've got the same issue.

Comment: Same issue here as well. Still no luck with a solution.

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce the problem you're having. This [simple demo](http://jsbin.com/ogona4/7) seems to work perfectly on my 1st gen ipod touch, running iOS 3.1

Comment: My iPhone 4 running iOS 4.1(?) has the same problem on that demo. Are you sure you're pressing the "next" button on the dropdown interface?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could use the focus event, in jQuery this would be:

```
$('#select2').focus(function () {
    // update select2's elements
});
```

Although the real question is when the iPhone overload comes in, and when the event get fired. And also can the select options be changed whilst in this view.

Comment: I've got the same problem as the OP. I've tried focus(), blur() and change(), but the iPhone still seems to be caching the list contents until you hit Next/Prev again.

Comment: Yup, same, tried focus(), blur() and change(), none of those work. Also, why upvote something that does not work and is not even tested.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my site. I was able to fix it by manually polling the `selectedIndex` property on the select control. That way it fires as soon as you "check" the item in the list. Here's a jQuery plugin I wrote to do this:

```
$.fn.quickChange = function(handler) {
    return this.each(function() {
        var self = this;
        self.qcindex = self.selectedIndex;
        var interval;
        function handleChange() {
            if (self.selectedIndex != self.qcindex) {
                self.qcindex = self.selectedIndex;
                handler.apply(self);
            }
        }
        $(self).focus(function() {
            interval = setInterval(handleChange, 100);
        }).blur(function() { window.clearInterval(interval); })
        .change(handleChange); //also wire the change event in case the interval technique isn't supported (chrome on android)
    });
};
```

You use it just like you would use the "change" event. For instance:

```
$("#mySelect1").quickChange(function() { 
    var currVal = $(this).val();
    //populate mySelect2
});
```

**Edit**: Android does not focus the select when you tap it to select a new value, but it also does not have the same problem that iphone does. So fix it by also wiring the old `change` event.